# Compile error: 'The type or namespace name 'Runtime' does not exist in the namespace 'MyAppNamespace.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors

I am writing a WPF client that consumes services from an ASP web service (VS2010, .net 4.0). It was working just fine until yesterday when I suddenly get the above compiler error. Double-clicking on the error takes me to Reference.cs and highlights just about anything along the lines of:

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=2)]

(The 'Runtime' object is highlighted as not being in the MyAppNameSpace).

I've tried googling this and re-adding the service reference and re-adding the assemby reference but nothing works and I'm completely stuck. Reference.cs is automatically generated and I'm still relatively new to VS2010 so I'm not sure where to go with this.

Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction...?

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to see the problem - it appears that VS has gone bananas. If I type 'System.', intellisense is bringing up a reference to an old (now non-existant) folder rather than the .net System assembly.
No wonder it's confused.
Any idea how I can force VS to rebuild the type libraries (or whatever its called in .net now)?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After hours of trying to solve it I realised I had a class in my library called system. What a cock.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you had defined a "System" namespace somewhere that the compiler and Intellisense were finding before the real "System".  The solution is to remove the offending namespace, then clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Initially that's what I thought... but there was no such namespace in the project so I don't understand quite where the reference came from (I had not changed namespaces or anything for some time). In the end I fixed it by re-copying the old project .sln and proj files from a backup, which implies something bad had happened to the existing ones.

Comment: If you still have the corrupted proj files you might doing a diff between them and the ones you restored from backup.  This should make it easy to see what changed.  I would like to know, and I'm sure others would as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a VB project only I had no old code as it was a new service reference. I did not have any other namespace with System in the name. The solution for me was to make the following series of replacements:

**VB**
in Reference.vb

1. Replace `System.` with nothing
2. Then replace `"Runtime.Serialization"` with `"System.Runtime.Serialization"`
3. Lastly replace `<Global.ComponentModel` with `<ComponentModel`

**C#**
in Reference.cs (I didn't try this but expect it will work)

1. Replace `System.` with nothing
2. Then replace `"Runtime.Serialization"` with `"System.Runtime.Serialization"`
3. Lastly replace `[Global.ComponentModel` with `[ComponentModel`

One other detail that might lead someone to a root cause is that the service wsdl was coming from an old style asp.net web service (.asmx), here: https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClassService.asmx?wsdl

**Update**
I've subsequently found that changing the target framework to 4.5.1 resolved my compilation issue. Also I had the root cause was that I had different framework versions targeted by my web project and the class library containing my service references. Once I changed them all to 4.5.1 everything was happy no changes to Reference.vb was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the sake of anyone looking for an answer in future - I gave up trying to fix it and copied a backup of the project files over the existing ones and brought the changes since them in manually. That fixed the corrupt referencing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with a different solution.

My project used to be called "JobRunner", but it changed to "NGB.JobRunner". In the project settings however the default namespace and assembly name was still "JobRunner", and the Reference.cs file was being generated with this namespace.

I have no idea why it was causing problems, but when I fixed the default project namespace and assembly name, and re-added the service reference, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. It was the upper case 'T' in time which was causing the issue. I was doing RunTime but the correct was 'Runtime'.

What a time waste due to a typo!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **`global`** keyword. That forces the namespace resolution to start at the very top.

```
 global::System.Runtime;
```

Some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier